# Override Creation for Monitors and Rules

Tags: powershell, scom

I want to create PowerShell scripts to override some parameter of my monitor and rule. I used the below code, but I have some errors. I want override my overidable parameter not enabled or something else. How can I doe this?

```
$mps = Get-SCOMManagementPack | ? {$_.Name -like "test"}
$overrideMp = Get-SCOMManagementPack -DisplayName "Overrides"

$overridename = "testmonitor.Overrides" 

$monitor = 'testmonitor'
$override = New-Object Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Configuration.ManagementPackMonitorPropertyOverride($overrideMp,$overridename)
$override.Monitor = $monitor

$override.Property = 'WarningThreshold'
$override.Value = 80
$override.DisplayName = "Overrides"

$overrideMp.Verify()
$overrideMp.AcceptChanges()
```

Errors:

```
error1: Exception setting "Property": "Cannot convert value "WarningThreshold" to
type "Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Configuration.ManagementPackMonitorProperty".
Error: "Unable to match the identifier name WarningThreshold to a valid enumerator
name.  Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again: Enabled,
TraceEnabled, Algorithm, AlgorithmPercentage, DefaultState, GenerateAlert,
AutoResolve, AlertPriority, AlertOnState, AlertSeverity, AlertMessage,
AlertParameter1, AlertParameter2, AlertParameter3, AlertParameter4,
AlertParameter5, AlertParameter6, AlertParameter7, AlertParameter8,
AlertParameter9, AlertParameter10, MemberInMaintenance, MemberUnavailable,
IgnoreMemberInMaintenance, IgnoreMemberUnavailable""
At line:1 char:2
+  $override.Property = $parametername
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

```
error2 : Exception calling "AcceptChanges" with "0" argument(s): "Database error.
MPInfra_p_ManagementPackInstall failed with exception: Failed to validate item:
testrule1"
At line:193 char:1
+ $MP.AcceptChanges()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ManagementPackException
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message looks rather clear to me. There is no property `WarningThreshold` in the [`ManagementPackMonitorProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.enterprisemanagement.configuration.managementpackmonitorproperty.aspx) enumeration. I don't have much experience with SCOM, but you probably need to override the property `AlertOnState` for monitors where the property `AlertSeverity` has the value [`Warning`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.enterprisemanagement.configuration.managementpackalertseverity.aspx).

Try something along the lines of this:

```
$mps | Get-SCOMMonitor | Where-Object {
  # (other selection criteria) -and
  $_.AlertSettings.AlertSeverity -eq 'Warning'
} | ForEach-Object {
  $ctx = Get-SCOMClass -Id $_.Target.Id
  # ...
  $override = New-Object ...
  $override.Monitor = $_
  $override.Property = 'AlertOnState'
  $override.Value = 80
  $override.Context = $ctx
  # ...
}
```

Code adopted from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30714.scom-2012-bulk-override-creation-for-monitors-and-rules-using-powershell.aspx) (probably the same place where you found it). Not sure if this works, though. Like I said, I have very little experience with SCOM, and I don't have a SCOM server available for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to debug it tomorrow in the office.

BTW, there is a third-party tool for override management called MPTuner: http://mpwiki.viacode.com/default.aspx?g=mptuner
It's free so you should try.

Roman.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite confusing, but there are two different type of overrides for each workflow type. For a monitor there are:

```
MonitorPropertyOverride
MonitorConfigurationOverride
```

You are using the first one, wgich is for standard parameters only, like Enabled, for example. For any custom parameters use Configuration Override.